# Not getting any audits while reviewing 'Suggested Edits' section

Tags: discussion

I have reviewed around 230 suggested edits but I've never come across any audit.

I fairly frequently see audits in Triage, Low Quality Posts, but never in Suggested Edits.

I am pretty sure they exist, since there are a bunch of questions about them. Or have they been taken out?

Comment: I received a suggested edit audit a few seconds ago, so they haven't been taken out: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7803457

Comment: Do you use the filter in the suggested edits queue?

Comment: I checked through some of your history, couldn't find any. Do you use SKIP in the suggested edits queue?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy I don't use Filter. Although 'suggested edit' queues most related to me at the front.

Comment: @Roombatron5000 Yes I do SKIP a lot. Got an audit ban a week back. So I've been pretty cautious. 
I skip in other categories as well. But they give me audits.

Comment: @iosDev82 The only audits in the suggested edits queue are fairly and pretty obvious spam/vandalism suggested edits. There is never an audit in that queue that should be "approved". So the correct choice for all audits in that queue is "Reject". So if you happen to SKIP many suggestions that you would probably reject, you would be skipping the audits.

Comment: Audits or no, please don't approve edits like this: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7802914 . Code formatting should only be used for code, not random words in paragraphs.

Comment: Hi Brad. Duly noted. 
Could you please direct me to a link that has guidelines for various reviews?